# Adding 10 minutes to a date from mysql datetime and comparing it to the time now

Tags: php

I can't figure out how to add 10 minutes to a time I am getting from mysql database the field structure is datetime.

Current code

```
$nowtime = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

$timeoflastlogin = $db->gettime();

//ADD 10 MINS TO TIME LAST ATTEMPTED 
$endtime = strtotime('+ 10 minutes', $timeoflastlogin );
//$endtime = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('+ 10 minutes', $timeoflastlogin );
```

This displays "
    2011-09-07 13:53:43 < time of last login
    2011-09-07 03:56:15 < now time
    2611< endtime - this is supposed to be time of last +10 mins "

I cannot work out how to add 10 mins to the time/date from mysql, I need to do this and then set a command to compare the time now and of last login so if it has been 10 minutes I can stop the user trying to login again!

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$timeoflastlogin` is **not** a Unix timestamp but a *string* - so you can't use that as a `$now` parameter for strtotime. This should work:

```
$endtime = strtotime('+ 10 minutes', strtotime( $timeoflastlogin ) );
```

or easier:

```
$endtime = strtotime( $timeoflastlogin ) + 600; // 10 minutes == 600 seconds
```

Comment: 2011-09-07 15:13:45< last logged in time
2011-09-07 04:13:54< now time
2011-09-07 03:23:45< end time

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly in the database:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(datefield, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
FROM ...
```

This saves you the PHP overhead of having to re-parse the date string into a time value, do the addition, then re-convert to a string.

Comment: I would of done this but the db query is used for other things

Comment: No reason you can't retrieve two copies of the field. `select datefield, date_add(datefield ...) as tenminutesfromnow`

Comment: that is a good point, maybe I need to rethink how I make my queries, do you think that would be a more efficient way of doing things then my way?

Comment: nothing wrong with the PHP time functions overall, but if this is going to be done for "many" records, it'd be more efficient to do the math in MySQL. strtotime and the like are very handy functions, but they're NOT particularly efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php.

Comment: Thanks for the reply the second "easier option" outputs 1315401706

The first option outputs the same, do I need to format this in date?

Comment: You can format your date using the format() method if you need to output it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have done it in the past:
Use php's mktime function:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

This lets you pass in values for day, month, year, etc (which you can pull out of your sql time).  If the minutes is greater than 60, it will automatically adjust the hours for you.  It will then return a time stamp.

To get this timestamp back into a sql date format, use the date function.

Something kind of like this:

```
echo date("M-d-Y", mktime($hour, $min + 10, $sec, $month, $day, $year));
```

You will have to adjust the "M-d-Y" to get the format you want.

Comment: thanks I have done this before but it makes a meal of doing what I wanted!