# PHP Future Date (Y-m-d H:i:s)

Tags: php, datetime

Is there a way to add, say, 10 minutes with date() but in the format (Y-m-d H:i:s)? I am doing a "time extended" piece to an auction and I can't seem to remember how to set this up. PHP manual isn't giving me much help, though that could be from me not searching around incorrectly. I also searched here, but couldn't really find an answer close to mine.

In conclusion:
I have a date, say "2013-05-29 17:00:00" that is dynamically pulled from the database. I need to make it "2013-05-29 17:10:00".

I bet there is something so seriously easy about it that I'll hit my head on my desk after getting the answer.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You could just do it in the database using `select my_date, date_add(my_date, interval 10 minute) as in_10_minutes from my_table;`

Comment: Take a look at this : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335153/adding-10-minutes-to-a-date-from-mysql-datetime-and-comparing-it-to-the-time-now

Comment: @RyanNaddy you, sir, need to make this an answer so I can upvote+accept it. Worked perfectly.

Comment: @RyanNaddy I'll accept it once SO lets me! Gotta wait another 5 minutes :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an alternative to the PHP method, since you are already getting the data from the database, why don't you just do it in the database.

```
$sql = $pdo->exec("select my_date, date_add(my_date, interval 10 minute) as in_10_minutes from my_table");
$rows = $sql->fetchAll();

foreach($rows as $row){
    echo $row["my_date"]."::".$row["in_10_minutes"];
}
```

Answer (score 10):

you can use:

```
 $closingTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($closingTime) + (60*10));
```

Answer (score 4):

Do this.

```
<?php
date('l jS F (Y-m-d)', strtotime('+10 minutes'));
??
```