# End a session after a period of time if the page has been inactive - PHP

Tags: php

I have a website in php which has a log in system. I would like to log the user out after 10min if the website is inactive. To do this I was going to use the following code:

```
session_start();
// set timeout period in seconds
$inactive = 600;
// check to see if $_SESSION['timeout'] is set
if(isset($_SESSION['timeout']) ) {
$session_life = time() - $_SESSION['start'];
   if($session_life > $inactive) { 
     session_destroy(); 
     header("Location: index.php"); 
   }
}
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
```

However when I run the website and refresh the page it logs out and directs the page to "index.php" even before the "600 seconds" have passed.

What might be the problem here and how can I know that the page has inactive?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335153/adding-10-minutes-to-a-date-from-mysql-datetime-and-comparing-it-to-the-time-now

Comment: How is `timeout` in `if(isset($_SESSION['timeout']) ) {` defined? It seems like it hasn't yet been assigned, in your posted code anyway.

Comment: Are you sure $_SESSION['start'] is set correctly? Also I don't get what $_SESSION['timeout'] is good for? Not needed imho...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
session_start();

// set timeout period in seconds
$session_timeout = 600;

if (!isset($_SESSION['last_visit'])) { $_SESSION['last_visit'] = time(); } // I like brackets!

if((time() - $_SESSION['last_visit']) > $session_timeout) { 
  session_destroy(); 
  header("Location: index.php"); // think about user feedback, "your session timed out" ... index.php?action=session_timeout
  exit; // <= IMPORTANT !!!
}


$_SESSION['last_visit'] = time();
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked! Now will the "counter" be reset if the website is active / used by the user? Or the user will be logged out (the session will stop) regardless?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're right, currently user will get logged off after 600 seconds ... will improve it ...

Comment: if I need to log the user out automatically the page needs to be refreshed. So I used the following code:

    <?php
          //refresh the page after 10min
          $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
          $sec = "601";
    ?>

Is there another way to do this without refreshing the page?

Thanks

Comment: You can use Javascript to redirect to another page also ... or use Ajax to stay on the same page and show a "logged off" message then in response.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you define `$_SESSION['start' ]`? I test this:

```
$session_life = time() - $_SESSION['start'];
echo $session_life ,' - ', $_SESSION['timeout'];
die();
```

And both `$session_life` and `$_SESSION['timeout']` has the same values so the question is, which value takes `$_SESSION['start']`?