# How should I make timer in PHP that can count timediff of the user form the last request?

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys I am trying to make a counter that count for 10 min form that last time user pressed the button(for ex requested anything).

What I did, I took timestamp in Mysql and code is below.

```
$timequery =" SELECT NOW() AS cur, ( SELECT lastclaim FROM table1 WHERE id =".$id." ) AS mytime "; 
if( $qry=mysql_query( $timequery ) )
{
    $timer1 =strtotime( mysql_result($qry, 0,'mytime')); 
    $timer2 =strtotime( mysql_result($qry, 0,'cur')); 
    $timer = abs( $timer2 - $timer1);
    return $timer;
}
```

Please suggest me better logic for this problem or guide me for improve this code.

Comment: You may also do it in JS, or via cookies, is it possible for you ?

Answer (score 0):

IMUO i wouldn't go to ask at database, you could do it with SESSIONs and you will have less DB access. I.E you coud do something like:

```
$nowtime = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

if(isset($_SESSION['timeOfLastAction']){
    $timeOfLastAction = $_SESSION['timeOfLastAction'];
}else{
    $timeOfLastAction =  $nowtime;
}

$endtime = strtotime( $timeOfLastAction ) + 600; // 10 minutes == 600 seconds

if($nowtime > $endtime){ //10 min or more from last action
    //do your stuff
    $_SESSION['timeOfLastAction'] = date('Y-m-d h:i:s'); //reassing
}
```

If you need/want to store at database you could change the `if{}else{}` part to your actual code.. but you have to access to database, store value, update the value in each request, etc. you could use a mysql native function like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE lastclaim <= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
AND id=$id
```

And you will avoid the data manipulation in PHP, you will recive a `user` only if the interval is >10 min.

Here a similar issue of yours: [Adding 10 minutes to a date from mysql datetime and comparing it to the time now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335153/adding-10-minutes-to-a-date-from-mysql-datetime-and-comparing-it-to-the-time-now)

I hope it helps!